# If something succeeds 100% 33% of the time, and 33% 66% of the time, how often does it succeed?

Tags: probability

How is the probability of success calculated if something succeeds $100$% $33$% of the time, and $33$% $66$% of the time? My best guess is $$\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{2}{3} = \frac{5}{9}$$

Comment: Be precise:  what about the remaining one percent of the time?

Comment: How do you measure success? How much better is full success to $33$% success?

Comment: "How often does it succeed" implies that success is binary (either something succeeds or it doesn't), while the question also references partial (percentages of) successes. You need to clarify.

Comment: Is it possible that you mean: "In one third of the cases it succeeds and additionally it succeeds in one third of the rest of the cases"? If yes, then your $\frac{5}{9}$ should be correct.

Comment: As a nitpick... $33\%$ is not the same as occurring $\frac{1}{3}$ of the time.  The fractions $\dfrac{33}{100}$ and $\dfrac{33}{99}$ despite having the same (*nonzero*) numerator have different denominators and are thus non-equal.

Comment: Yes. This is why I asked.

Comment: As far as your question is concerned... yes... $\Pr(A) = \Pr(B)\Pr(A\mid B) + \Pr(B^c)\Pr(A\mid B^c)$... the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).  Assuming you were to phrase the question correctly and unambiguously, your result is correct.  An example of a well phrased question like what you ask: "If I have three biased coins, the first of which always lands on heads, and the remaining two each land on heads $\frac{1}{3}$ of the time and tails the rest, if I pick one of these coins uniformly at random and flip what is probability of getting heads

Comment: Isn't $33$% $66$% of the time $=$ $100$% $22$% of the time...

Comment: You need to ask a proper question to be able to get an answer.  The probability of success implies that success is binary, not partial.  You can certainly ask the expected value of the success fraction, which (aside from the difference between $33\%$ and $\frac 13) is what you have computed.

Comment: @e2-e4 yeah that's how I figured out how to calculate it. To everyone else, I am aware this is a dumb question. For some reason I am slow on figuring out how to calculate it but I did before the first comment. There are also some trivial probability questions on this stack exchange, maybe it has some value or maybe it has negative value. I got what I need to move forward, balancing attack vectors and defenses in a game theoretical system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How is the probability of success calculated if something succeeds $100$% $33$% of the time, and $33$% $66$% of the time? My best guess is $$\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{2}{3} = \frac{5}{9}$$

Only should $33\%$ be $1/3$, which it is not; it is only approximately so.  Otherwise that is the *correct approach*. By the Law of Total Probability, the probability of success when partitioned over "times" is:

$$\mathsf P(S)=\sum_{t}\mathsf P(S\mid T=t)\,\mathsf P(T=t)$$

But $33\%+66\%=99\%$, so what happens the other $1\%$ of the time? No success? Let's go with that.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(S)&=100\%\,33\%+33\%\,66\%+0\%\,1\%\\&=54.78\%\end{align}$$

Adjust the figures if something else happens.

---

But of course, if the success rate is *actually*: certain in $1/3$ of the time, and $1/3$ in the remaining $2/3$ of the time, then:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(S)&=1\cdot\tfrac 13+\tfrac 13\cdot\tfrac 23\\&=\tfrac 59\end{align}$$